# Depth-object search based on a path

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion

I need help with tree walking to find matches.

1. Search the object recursively to find a TEXT_TO_MATCH and return it's PATH
2. With that PATH walk though every array it finds, until it finds another item
3. Search that item to see if it has a path the SAME LENGTH as TEXT_TO_MATCH path but just in a different position in some PARENT array

EG: TEXT_TO_MATCH exists at `.a[0].b.c.[0].value`,

It should return all values which have the path:

`.a[ANY_INDEX].b.c[ANY_INDEX].value`

```
const pathToMatch = findText(DATA, 'A') // returns .a[0].b.c[0].value

findObjectInTree(DATA, pathToMatch) // returns all data which appear at .a[ANY_INDEX].b.c[ANY_INDEX].value
```

For example, my input data looks like this:

```
{
  a:[
    { b:{ c:[{value:'A'}]}},
    { b:{ c:[{foo:1},{value:'B'}]}},
    { b:{ c:[{value:'C', 
        b:  { c:
                [ {value:'D'} ]
            } 
        }]
    }}
  ],
  a1:[{ b:{ c:[{value:'AA'}]}}]
}
```

The result would be:
`['A','B','C']`

Why?

- A,B,C *ARE* returned as they are on the same object path
  `.a[ANY_INDEX].b.c[ANY_INDEX].value`
- D are *NOT* returned because it is deeper in the path at
  `.a[ANY_INDEX].b.c[ANY_INDEX].b.c[ANY_INDEX].value`
- AA are *NOT* returned because it is on a different object key `a1`
  `.a1[ANY_INDEX].b.c[ANY_INDEX].value`

The actual data my be larger and more nested- but a text match will always exist on the SAME path but at a different index of a ARRAY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the path to the found string, second collect values with this path:

```js
const obj = {
    a: [
        { b: { c: [{ value: 'A' }] } },
        { b: { c: [{ foo: 1 }, { value: 'B' }] } },
        {
            b: {
                c: [{
                    value: 'C',
                    b: {
                        c:
                            [{ value: 'D' }]
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    ],
    a1: [
        { b: { c: [{ value: 'A1' }] } },
        { b: { c: [{ foo: 1 }, { value: 'B1' }] } },
        {
            b: {
                c: [{
                    value: 'C1',
                    b: {
                        c:
                            [{ value: 'D1' }]
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    ],
};

const str = 'A';

// first find the value and its path from the root
const path = findPath(obj, str);

if (!path) {
    console.error(new Error(`The string "${str}" not found`));
} else {

    // walk in path and collect values

    const collected = [];
    collect(obj, path, collected);
    console.log(collected);

}

function collect(obj, path, collected) {

    const part = path.shift();
    if (!path.length) {
        part in obj && collected.push(obj[part]);
        return;
    }
    if (part === 0) { // it's an array, iterate
        for (const item of obj) {
            collect(item, path.slice(), collected);
        }
        return;
    }
    part in obj && collect(obj[part], path, collected);

}


function findPath(obj, str, path = [], isArray) {

    for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(obj)) {

        const out = path.concat(isArray ? 0 : key);

        const isChildArray = Array.isArray(val);

        if (isChildArray || val.__proto__.constructor.name === 'Object') {
            const found = findPath(val, str, out, isChildArray);
            if (found) {
                return found;
            }
        } else if (typeof val === 'string' && val.includes(str)) {
            return out;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It's seems on the right track but has 2 problems.

Firstly, it doesn't need to match that `str` value every time. Just the FIRST time to find the depth it should search. Secondly, it doesn't seem to work for a larger objects.

Comment: @Ycon refined, pls check whether the new version works for you. if not let's continue working

Comment: Closer- however it seems to returning items that are not at the same 'path' depth. For example, it returns something at `foo[0].bar[0].baz[0].value` and `foo[0].value` it seems. If the initial found path was `foo[0].bar[0].baz[0].value` it should only find items at that depth such as `foo[0].bar[1].baz[0].value`

Comment: @Ycon if you give me more test data in the question like you described in the kast comment that would give something to work with

Comment: Appreciate that, I've just updated the original question with more clarity (but I think you understand, as your answer is very close). Here's a bit more data- https://dpaste.org/pSeJT

Comment: @Ycon I've added your data to the code, nothing actually changed in the logic (some tweaks / rearranging / error handling). It still works as you described. So someone of us isn't clear 100% in understanding. If you find it's OK now pls upvote/accept it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a [depth-first search (DFS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), with some modifications to keep track of the path we have taken while traversing the object. When we find a match, we can then iterate through all the other elements at the same depth (i.e., in the same parent array) to find other matches.

This solution does not require any external libraries and should be able to handle large and deeply nested data structures, as long as they fit in memory. However, if you are dealing with very large data structures, you might need to look into more efficient algorithms or data structures.

That also needs to store the path of the first found match, and then looking for matches at that path (ignoring the array index) in all subsequent array elements we encounter in our traversal.
Something like:

```js
function findObjectInTree(data, textToMatch) {
    const path = findPath(data, textToMatch);
    if (!path) {
        return null;
    }
    return findValues(data, path);
}

function findPath(obj, target, path = []) {
    if (typeof obj === 'string') {
        return obj.includes(target) ? path : null;
    }
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
        for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            const result = findPath(obj[i], target, [...path, i]);
            if (result) return result;
        }
    } else if (typeof obj === 'object' && obj !== null) {
        for (let key in obj) {
            const result = findPath(obj[key], target, [...path, key]);
            if (result) return result;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function findValues(obj, path, idx = 0) {
    if (idx === path.length) {
        return [obj];
    }
    const key = path[idx];
    if (!(key in obj)) {
        return [];
    }
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
        let values = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            values = [...values, ...findValues(obj[i], path, idx + 1)];
        }
        return values;
    } else {
        return findValues(obj[key], path, idx + 1);
    }
}

// Your JSON data
const data = {
    a: [
        { b: { c: [{ value: 'A' }] } },
        { b: { c: [{ foo: 1 }, { value: 'B' }] } },
        { b: { c: [{ value: 'C', b: { c: [{ value: 'D' }] } }] } }
    ]
};

console.log(findObjectInTree(data, 'A'));  // Output: [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ]
```

This JavaScript code first defines a function `findPath` that performs a depth-first search to find the path to the first occurrence of the target value in the JSON object.

It then defines a function `findValues` that also performs a depth-first search to find all values in the JSON object that follow the same path as the target value, regardless of their positions in parent arrays.

Finally, it defines a function `findObjectInTree` that uses these two functions to find all instances of a value in a JSON structure following the path of the first occurrence of the value.

Note: This code assumes that the JSON object does not have arrays as keys. If your actual JSON data can have arrays as keys, you will need to adjust the code to handle that situation.

Comment: Thanks VonC but it doesn't return all values, it only seems to return a single value that matches. EG `findObjectInTree(obj,'a')` output `['a']`

Comment: Update code seems to return the same result

Comment: @Ycon Right (I was treating array indices as if they were object keys). I have updated the code (again).

Comment: Nice, it is closer- a small oversight of mine- it should actually be an '.includes' for the text match. I tried adjusting your answer buy kept running into issues changing the "findPath" `obj === target ` to `obj.includes(target)` as it says obj.includes isn't a function.

Do you know how to modify that bit to get it working?

Comment: @Ycon The `includes` method is available on arrays and strings in JavaScript, but not on objects. If you want to check whether a string exists within another string (which seems to be your use case), you can use `includes` on the string.  I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's testable solution.

In the **first phase**, the structure of `data` is recursively traversed to find the first matched string (if there're multiple occurrences *may exist*, this algorithm won't be searching for them though). Once the match is found, recursion immediately breaks and saves the path along its way up: for dictionary-like objects it stores the key of the relevant child item; for arrays it's their numeric index.

In the **second phase**, another recursion happens, but this time around it goes deeper whenever the current path satisfies the structure of the reference path. So for string items of the reference path, we recurse only if the current element is a non-array object that has a corresponding own key. While for numeric items, the current element has be an array; and if it is then the search is continued for each of its child elements. Once the end of the reference path is reached, we finally check if the current element is a string, and add it to the search results.

```js
function findObjectInTree (data, textToMatch) {

    let hasOwn = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
    let matchPath = [];
    let strings = [];

    function findFirstMatch (node) {
        if (typeof node == 'object') {
            if (node == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (Array.isArray(node)) {
                for (let i = 0; i < node.length; i++) {
                    if (findFirstMatch(node[i])) {
                        matchPath.unshift(i);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
            let keys = Object.keys(node);
            for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                if (findFirstMatch(node[keys[i]])) {
                    matchPath.unshift(keys[i]);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        if (typeof node == 'string') {
            return (node == textToMatch);
        }
        return false;
    }

    function findOtherItems (node, depth) {
        if (depth == matchPath.length) {
            if (typeof node == 'string') {
                strings.push(node);
            }
            return;
        }
        if (typeof node != 'object' || node == null) {
            return;
        }
        let pathItem = matchPath[depth];
        if (Number.isInteger(pathItem)) {
            if (Array.isArray(node)) {
                for (let i = 0; i < node.length; i++) {
                    findOtherItems(node[i], depth + 1);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (hasOwn.call(node, pathItem)) {
            findOtherItems(node[pathItem], depth + 1);
        }
    }

    if (!findFirstMatch(data)) {
        return null;
    }

    findOtherItems(data, 0);

    return { matchPath, strings };
}

function test (data, textToMatch) {

    console.log('Search for:', textToMatch);
    let result = findObjectInTree(data, textToMatch);
    if (result) {
        console.log('> Match found at:', result.matchPath.join(','));
        console.log('> Strings:', result.strings.join(','));
    }
    else {
        console.log('> No match found');
    }
}

let data = {
    a:[
        { b:{ c:[{value:'A'}]}},
        { b:{ c:[{foo:1},{value:'B'}]}},
        { b:{ c:[{value:'C',
            b:  { c:
                [ {value:'D'} ]
                }
            }]
        }}
    ]
};

test(data, 'A');
test(data, 'B');
test(data, 'C');
test(data, 'I do not exist');
```

*PS: leave a comment if something doesn't work properly.*

Comment: Thanks, it seems close but doesn't seem to work for larger complex objects with nested arrays. Are it doesn't find matches in those cases

Comment: @Ycon You can provide those complex cases in the question to make it more clear what you are working with.